# How to individualize DataExplorer reports?

Tags: r

I would like to increase the plot of plot_missing from the `DataExplorer` package.

```
config <- list(
              "plot_str" = list(
                                "type" = "diagonal",
                                "fontSize" = 35,
                                "width" = 1400,
                                "height" = 3000,
                                "margin" = list("left" = 50, "right" = 100)
                                ),
              "plot_missing" = list(
                                ),
              )

create_report(df, config = config)
```

When I add "`height`" to the list of plot_missing:

```
"plot_missing" = list("height" = 3000),
```

I receive

```
Error in plot_missing(data = list(Pos = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, : 
unused argument (height = 3000)
```

Comment: From your title, I assume you don't need the other components? If that's the case, you can use `plot_missing()` alone and configure the output format. If not, I don't think there is a way to control figure size. Maybe you could also try the [missing_only](https://boxuancui.github.io/DataExplorer/reference/plot_missing.html) argument to reduce the overall columns?

Comment: Thank you! You'e the author, right? May I silly ask why it is not possible? Can't it be possible or just not yet? However, great package! When you keep on doing, it will definitely become my most used package for every new data set. It probably is already, I just need some more (individual) options and plots though :)

Comment: If you look at the [report template](https://github.com/boxuancui/DataExplorer/blob/master/inst/rmd_template/report.rmd#L19-L20), all the figures are set to a fixed height and width. No matter how you send in parameters, they will be force set back to the default value. While it is possible to customize individual plot size, it might not be easy, nor the top priority at the moment. I recommend calling individual plot functions and create your own report in this case.